# Firebug Shows Long Wait Time for POST Request

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

I am doing an ajax post request for about 1.5mb of data. Firebug says that this takes 14.26s, but 11.49s of that is "Waiting."

What exactly does this mean and what may be the potential cause(s)?

Note that this is an ajax request that occurs after a button is pressed. There are no other requests going on at the same time.

Comment: Without more info, it could be anything. First thing that comes to mind is slow shared hosting + less than optimized SQL statements could easily create that kind of delay.

Comment: I timed the server side function that maps to the POST, and it only takes 1.5s to run (including all SQL). Also, this is running on a local webserver (IIS) w/ virtually no other activity and a decent computer (core i3 cpu, 3gb ram)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a previous SO question that is similar:

[What exactly is the 'Waiting for response' msg on Firebug's Net tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400829/what-exactly-is-the-waiting-for-response-msg-on-firebugs-net-tab)